# flash plugin for phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

I am developing one application in html,css,javascript in phonegap. in that application i need a flash plugin coding for javascript to enable audio/video for my application purpose if anybody know the solution please get back to me as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you developing for iPhone via Phonegap? Because the iPhone doesn't support Flash.

Comment: No Damien i am developing in android via phonegap.another doubt i have. like in my application one button is there. if i click that button means it goto mobile settings like volume settings its possible in phonegap?

Comment: Similar thread is running at here.....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546825/how-to-play-an-swf-file-in-phonegap?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to override the onCreate method in your Java class that extends DroidGap and put something like this in there:

```
WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings(); 
settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON); // Turn Flash plugin on
```

Not exactly sure if this can be done in your class that extends DroidGap but it can definitely be done if you edit the DroidGap.java source!

Check out this link for details:

http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/b37c59f2ac532fe3/d5121817269e1ae1?lnk=gst&q=flash#d5121817269e1ae1

Comment: adding this is causing a force close. are there any extra permissions or changes to be made to manifest for this? its getting a nullpointer exception on appView.getSettings()

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546825/how-to-play-an-swf-file-in-phonegap?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and it is working perfectly fine in my android app. I have embed flash site inside cordova app.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
    super.init();
    super.appView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    super.loadUrl("http://bezalelgreenarts.com/");//flash based site

}
```