# Open swf in Android System Browser not in Phonegap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want my Phonegap App to open a Flash-Webpage in the Android Browser, not in Webview. I tried it with a normal HTML Anchor Tag. This doestn't work. Window.open also opens the page internally and I get the message: "Alternate HTML Content should be placed here. This requires the Adobe Flash Player." Strange is, that when I click on the following Link "Get Flash" the Android Browser opens...
I use JQuery Mobile 1.0rc2 and Phonegap 1.1.0 on a Samsung Galaxy S with Android 2.3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already set the `rel="external"` and `target="_blank"` properties on the link and configure the PhoneGap.plist "ExternalHosts" section?

This [forum post](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquerymobile-phonegap-open-external-link-in-browser) may help.

Comment: Thats it. I added the domain to the phonegap.xml as "access allowed". Links listed there seem to get executed allways internally. So I removed the domain and it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Flash for PhoneGap

Take a look a this :

[How to play an swf file in phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546825/how-to-play-an-swf-file-in-phonegap)

Comment: Is there no other way? The Flash page runs on a blazeds application server, so I can`t put it into the phonegap App anyway.