# Android PhoneGap with jQuery mobile html5 embedding flash

Tags: java, android, flash, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am a complete novice at android and Java, my application works in my android tablet except for my embedded flash files. I am aware that flash works in android, because I have flash player installed, I have tested my index.html in Mozilla Firefox it displays the embedded flash files, and I have tested my index.html in Google Chrome the embedded flash files do not work. Is there a way in which my flash files can be read from my index.html, so that when it is exported as an application it can display the flash movies?

```
     <!--Embedded flash movie-->
      <p>
       <object width="710" height="493">
      <param name="movie" value="welcome.swf">
      <embed src="yaa/welcome.swf"
             width="710" height="493"> </embed>
    </object>
      </p>
```

I've tried literally tried everything, from swf object, to webview, the manifest permissions is fine, but all fail to display my flash movies. 
The www folder contains the assets folder and the structure of the assets folder is; yaa (folder with flash swf files), cordova 2.5.0,index.html, css, javascripts. The java code is:

```
package com.helloapp.namespace.myhelloworld;
```

import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;

```
public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}

 }
```

Comment: Add this line into your AndroidManifest file: android:hardwareAccelerated="true" also http://stackoverflow.com/a/6054634/1848600

Comment: Thanks but I have already added the android:hardwareAccelerated="true"and I have already placed the websettings plugin it does not still display the flash movies within the application.

Comment: android 4.4+ dose not support the  flash player(fly/swf) video

Answer (score 0):

android 4.4+ dose not support the flash player(fly/swf) video